# Network folder asks password everytime accessing files

Tags: networking, samba, shared-folders, nas

Hi I am using USB HDD as NAS and I have shared it over FTP and SMB.

From windows the network folder is mapped and it is getting acessed without issues. But from Linux I am getting error while accessing files, everytime it asks for password. I have used ftp connection for mapping NAS folder.
Is there any other way to access network folder files as smoothly as windows? Each time I open file it tries to download it in temp folder before opening. Whereas in windows it opens right away.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: I am using Kubuntu 22.04

Comment: You either change ftp settings, or access files using SMB as well.

Comment: SMB connection gives error. I tried "sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=..." but it is giving following message: mount error: Server abruptly closed the connection.
This can happen if the server does not support the SMB version you are trying to use.
The default SMB version recently changed from SMB1 to SMB2.1 and above. Try mounting with vers=1.0.
mount error(112): Host is down

Comment: I have corrected the command but now I get following error: "mount error: could not resolve address for MyFolder: Unknown error"

Comment: on server I can see network neighborhood as "smb://MyFolder"

Answer (score 0):

Following command worked at last -

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o rw,vers=1.0,credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials //192.168.0.14/sharedfold /home/user/sharedfold
```